# CSS Grid Columns Expand Past Parent, Absolute Positioned Div

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I Have a parent div that is relative positioned. It has an image in it that sets the height of the div. Then, there is an absolute position div inside that is grid display. The columns inside the grid are expanding past the parent div which is set to 100%. Here is a code example.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="/imageurl" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-overlay" style="display:grid;grid-template-columns:33% 33% 33%;height:100%;position:absolute">
    <div class="overlay-item" style="height:100%">Item 1</div>
    <div class="overlay-item" style="height:100%">Item 1</div>
    <div class="overlay-item" style="height:100%">Item 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `overlay-item` divs extend past the `image-overlay` div. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image (which defines the width of the outer wrapper) is in a container inside the outer wrapper - so adding `inline-block` to the outer wrapper ensures that the outer wrapper matches the width created by the image.

Also made a couple of changes to your code (along with removing inline styles):

- change `grid-template-columns` to `1fr 1fr 1fr` instead of `33% 33% 33%` so that it *fills* the horizontal space fully,
- added `display: block` to `img` element to remove the whitespace below the image (and for that matter any *inline element*).

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay-item {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-overlay">
    <div class="overlay-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="overlay-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="overlay-item">Item 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it basically came down to a z-index issue. Once, I added z-index:2 it works.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a z-index issue. I need to add this to the absolute div and it positioned fine after that.